# Having trouble getting my button to display a click count

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Hello I am having trouble with my code. This is built on javascript and node. I want a count to be viewed every time a button is clicked for a story on my website www.groupwrites.com , Here is the code I have so far.

```js
var clicks = 0;

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

```html
<div class="media-box-footer">
  <div class="media-box-categories">
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span id="clicks">0</span>
  </div>

  <p><a href="/stories/<%= story._id %>" type="button" onClick="onClick()" class="btn" role="button">Read</a>
```

Everything is displaying just fine. I click the read button though, (this takes me to a different page) but when I come back the counter is still at 0. Any help would be AMAZING, as I am stuck for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript variable is not going to maintain its scope and value when you exit the page, which is what you are doing.

If you open the page in a new tab, it will as you can see with my update below -- adding `target="_blank"`

However, if you want to maintain the value over time, you need a datastore to store that value, such as a database.

```js
var clicks = 0;

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

```html
<div class="media-box-footer">
  <div class="media-box-categories">
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span id="clicks">0</span>
  </div>

  <p><a href="/stories/<%= story._id %>" target="_blank" type="button" onClick="onClick()" class="btn" role="button">Read</a>
```

Comment: how can I save to my mongodb? For some reason I added the target blank, but only the first story in the index is getting the count , no matter which story I click the Read button on.

Comment: I don't know MongoDB, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the state of a counter locally on the users computer (browser) you can use any of the available local data stores such as localStorage.

This code should work as you would like it to, given the specs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;
window.onload = function() {
    var counterNow = localStorage.getItem('counter') || 0;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = counterNow;
}
function onClick(event) {
    var counterNow = localStorage.getItem('counter') || 0;
  counterNow = parseInt(counterNow);
  counterNow++;
    localStorage.setItem('counter', counterNow);
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = counterNow;
};
</script>
<div class="media-box-footer">
  <div class="media-box-categories">
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span id="clicks">0</span>
  </div>

<a href="/stories/<%= story._id %>" type="button" onClick="onClick()" class="btn" role="button">Read</a>
```

If you want to store the data across multiple page loads from different users then you need to store the counter variable on the server.

Comment: thank you this works great. However for some reason, only the counter on the first story is increasing, no matter which story's "read" button I click. And the rest of the counters stay at 0. Any idea why this may be? Also I def want the data stored, from whoever, wherever views it. Displaying how many times that button has ever been clicked anywhere exactly like a youtube video displaying its' views.

Comment: This is the code for the top of the media boxes 
   <% stories.forEach(function(story){ %>
         <div class="media-box <%= story.category %>" id="thumbhover">
              <div class="media-box-image">
                  <div data-thumbnail="<%= story.image %>"></div>
              </div>